Question on "Theory of the alternative" from linear algebra
Theory of the alternative:
Either $Ax=b$ has a solution, or else there is a $y$ such that $yA=0$, $yb \neq 0$.

A basic result of linear algebra is given a matrix $A$, the codomain of the corresponding linear transformation is a direct sum of the left null space and column space. Isn't this an equivalent statement to the theory of the alternative?

Also, what would be lost in the following modified version of the theory of the alternative:
Either $Ax=b$ has a solution, or $b^TA=0$.
If we treat the "or" as exclusive, then wouldn't this modified version say the same thing? It's also stating that the codomain of $A$ is a direct sum of the column space and left null space.
............. Am I missing something here?

Your modified version is not true, for instance consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, b = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

You write $Ax$ and $yA$?

@DietrichBurde $y$ is a row vector, $x$ is a column vector. $yb$ wouldn't make sense, otherwise.

What you are calling the "theory of the alternative" holds over arbitrary fields.  What you are calling "a basic result of linear algebra" is not a basic result of linear algebra since it breaks for many fields.  So they cannot be equivalent statements.

A vector $b\in\Bbb R^m$ can fail to be an element of a subspace $V\subset R^m$ without being orthogonal to it.

I think this is more customarily called “Fredholm’s alternative”.
